# XLS or CSV Historic EDGAR CIK list, for a specific state?

Tags: data-request, usa, business

I'm searching for historic business physical addressees for California, I've found that the CIK header for EDGAR states the company name and address. 
Is there a method to download a file with all the CIK for a given year?

<sup>CIK is a Central Index Key with the SEC's (Securities and Exchange Commission) EDGAR system (Electronic Data Gathering, Analysis and Retrieval)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download everything from 2009 onwards from here:
https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets.html get the file submissions.csv and there you will find the submitter's CIK and address information.